# Django Rest Framework get_queryset being called more than once

Tags: django-rest-framework

When a request is made to my ListAPIView , the get_queryset() method is being called multiple times. It was being called 4 times until I removed the default django model permissions, but now it is still being called twice. What else could be causing the repeat call.

```
class PropertyPledgeList(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = PledgeListSerializer

    ordering_fields = ('amount_cents')

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        return get_object_or_404(Property, slug=slug).pledges.all().prefetch_related("user")
```

Answer (score -1):

The duplicate queries are a result of the `get_object_or_404()`.

If you want to retrieve the parent object from the URL keyword arguments you can set it as an attribute in the dispatch method, which is only called one time, then access the already retrieved object in `get_queryset()`.

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound

class PropertyPledgeList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = PropertyPledge.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PledgeListSerializer

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.property = Property.objects.get(id=kwargs['slug'])
        except Property.DoesNotExist:
            self.property = None
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.property:
            raise NotFound
        return self.property.get_pledges()
```